# 0x-API response not working as expected for WETH-USDT and UNI-WETH

Tags: solidity, contract-development, blockchain, erc-20, 0x

I am using the below official contract given in documentation of Ox, for swapping ERC20 coins.

---

[0x-Smart-Contract](https://docs.0x.org/0x-api-swap/guides/use-0x-api-liquidity-in-your-smart-contracts)

---

So,The transactions like LINK-WETH, WETH-DAI, DAI-WETH, WETH-LINK, etc are working the quotes are given below:

---

[WETH-DAI](https://api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?sellToken=0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2&buyToken=0x6b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f&sellAmount=10000000000000000&excludedSources=Uniswap_V2),
[WETH-LINK](https://api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?sellToken=0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2&buyToken=0x514910771af9ca656af840dff83e8264ecf986ca&sellAmount=10000000000000000&excludedSources=Uniswap_V2)

[DAI-WETH](https://api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?sellToken=0x6b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f&buyToken=0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2&sellAmount=10000000000000000&excludedSources=Uniswap_V2),
[LINK-WETH](https://api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?sellToken=0x514910771af9ca656af840dff83e8264ecf986ca&buyToken=0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2&sellAmount=10000000000000000&excludedSources=Uniswap_V2)

---

The above transactions are working fine but for transactions for WETH-USDT and UNI-WETH are failing for some reason, they directly display's transaction may fail, insufficient funds on meta-mask conformation screen.

Below are the quotes I am using,

---

[WETH-USDT](https://api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?sellToken=0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2&buyToken=0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7&sellAmount=10000000000000000&excludedSources=Uniswap_V2),
[UNI-WETH](https://api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?sellToken=0x1f9840a85d5aF5bf1D1762F925BDADdC4201F984&buyToken=0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2&sellAmount=10000000000000000&excludedSources=Uniswap_V2)

---

The above two quotes are failing, even when I have the max allowance and enough token balance.

When I Click on Proceed any-way on meta-mask it displays error on ether scan. UNI::approve:amount exceeds 96 bits.

If any one finds any solution or explanation your help is really appreciated.

Comment: When I click on proceed anyway,
Ether scan displays error:

Comment: Hi Ashish, do you have the transaction IDs/etherscan links for these failed swaps? It would help quite a bit with debugging.